# minlines in gvimrc

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, gvim

I notice when I work with larger Mardown files, the syntax highlighting is
broken if I skip around the page. This seems to fix the issue:

```
syntax sync minlines=999
```

but if I put it into my `_gvimrc`, it doesnt do anything. Is it possible to
save this setting?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that syntax configuration is loaded for specific filetypes in Vim, so you want that change to apply for the Markdown type, so it's loaded as part of syntax rules (more specifically, after the built-in syntax rules) whenever you open a file of that type.

You can add more syntax rules for Markdown files by creating a file with path `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` (or `%HOME%\vimfiles\after\syntax\markdown.vim` on Windows) and add the `syntax sync minlines=999` to that file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I dont want a Markdown specific solution. Is a general solution available?

Comment: Perhaps via an autocommand

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
let g:markdown_minlines = 999
```

Comment: This is probably documented somewhere (maybe `:help ft-markdown`?). Adding the reference would improve this answer